# Spurious comma appears when combining hyperref pdfa with hyperxmp

Tags: hyperref, luatex, pdf-a, hyperxmp

I'm authoring a document using LuaLatex / TexLive v. 6:2016-33.20160520 on Fedora 25. When I use both the hyperref and hyperxmp packages a strange comma appears at the very bottom right of the page (to the right of the page number), after compiling the document twice in a row.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Simple code to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\begin{document}
Text.
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. Perhaps you need an update?

Comment: Did not happen for me. TeXlive2016 Ubuntu, everything current.

Comment: I see it, and also with pdflatex but in another place.

Comment: Now I see it, when compiled with pdflatex. Comma appears to right of Text, about the distance of a paragraph indent. But I still do not see it anywhere on the page, with lualatex.

Comment: I think you can avoid it by loading hyperxmp before hyperref *and* by adding at least one pdf info, like e.g pdfauthor.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In pdflatex, I can make the spurious comma disappear by adding `\author{yada}` to the preamble. Edit: I see that our comments crossed!

Comment: Encountering as well the same problem https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/690724/48642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ulrike and I both noted, the problem goes away when you provide an author. Since PDF/A needs an author, this should not be a problem in actual usage.

Apparently the code anticipates more one or more authors, and does not correctly initialize if there are NO authors. I quickly looked at the code, and did not see any obvious reason why.

The slightly different behavior observed among those who commented, suggests that the `pdfx` package (or an included package) has had a code modification somewhere along the line.

If you find that this also happens when you provide detailed metadata, then get back and mention it. Something like that would be more serious.

Comment: Indeed, changing my hypersetup section by adding pdfauthor did fix the glitch. However, it's a bit more subtle than might be expected. The test example above isn't really the document I'm interested of course, it's just a simple test case. In my real PDF, I already had the pdfauthor information included (along with a bunch of other metadata). I have found that putting pdfauthor *first* fixes the glitch. I suspect this behavior isn't totally right.

Comment: OK I think I see what I did wrong. I was missing a comma between pdftitle and pdfauthor. So the pdfauthor field went missing as a result.

Comment: Seems like I have I more serious case: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/690724/48642