# Spurious comma with LuaLatex, hyperxmp, hyperref and pdfa

Tags: hyperref

I compile the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperxmp} 
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\hypersetup{
    keeppdfinfo,
    pdftitle={test},
    pdfauthor={sdaf},
    pdfapart=1,
    pdfaconformance=B,
}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

and somehow I get interesting results. [image]

I get the backtick at the beginning of the page. I need the variables in `hypersetup` to get rid of the warnings. When I disable the package `hyperxmp` it vanishes, when I remove the option `pdfa` it vanishes as well.

Honestly don't know how to get rid of this backtick. Following the [old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365600/48642)  didn't help either. I've share my log [temporarily](https://ctxt.io/2/AABQPIE1Eg)

Comment: well it is a bug in hyperxmp, so report it to the author. The alternative is to use the pdfmanagement https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655531/2388

Comment: Thx for the hint. I've tried to contact the author. Regarding `DocumentMetadata` I've found [only](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex-dev/required/latex-lab/documentmetadata-support-code.pdf). Reviewing the document I'm not clear if `pdfmoddate` and/or `pdfcreationdate` are supported. According to the documentation not really. But perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: the documentation for the xmp-metadata is in l3pdfmeta.pdf. It describes also how to set the dates (if you really want to change them.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked the author of the package and his reply was:

> Try loading `hyperref` before `hyperxmp`.
>
> `hyperxmp` was written to hook into `hyperref`'s argument-processing
> routines, which it does by rewriting some of them.  When you load
> `hyperref` after `hyperxmp`, `hyperref` undoes all of `hyperxmp`'s changes.
> Although `hyperxmp` takes great strides to function correctly in this
> case, every update to `hyperref` breaks something new in `hyperxmp`.  I
> should probably just give up and issue an error message if the
> packages are loaded in the "wrong" order.

and running the code with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{hyperxmp} 
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\hypersetup{
    keeppdfinfo,
    pdftitle={test},
    pdfauthor={sdaf},
    pdfapart=1,
    pdfaconformance=B,
}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

fixes the problem. Thx for pointing out where to source of the error might be and thx for making it clear what solution should be applied!